# Why does password comparison fail when they match?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm encountering an issue in my Node.js application where the password comparison using Bcrypt always fails, even though I'm confident that the password is correct. I've manually inserted a user into my MongoDB database, and when attempting to authenticate the user, the Bcrypt compare method returns false. Here is a snippet of my login route:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ EmailValue: req.body.EmailValue })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed 1" });
      }

      bcrypt.compare(req.body.PasswordValue, user[0].PasswordValue, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed 2" });
        }
        if (result) {
          // Authentication successful logic here
        } else {
          return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed 3" });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

Its important to mention that i dont use a reqistration method. Iam Creating the users manually into mongoDb

Is there anything I might be missing or any common pitfalls in this scenario? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I've already checked the following:

1. Console logs for values, which seem correct.
2. Hash Value in Mongodb

Comment: How are you creating the hash you store in Mongo?

Comment: @Adrian Lynch iam Using the following Generator for that : https://bcrypt.online/

Comment: Try generating a hash from the same Node bcrypt lib. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, that worked, but iam really dont want to provide a registration. The users are meant to be Created by a DB admin

Comment: @TomTietz A db admin shouldn't choose passwords for users. They should at best create users without a password, for which the application then would generate a password reset (or invite) email

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the online Bcrypt generator:

PW with: https://bcrypt.online/        -> Wont work

PW with: https://bcrypt-generator.com/       -> works!

So if you are in the same situation as i am i woul recommend you not to use https://bcrypt.online/   to generate your User password -hashvalues